# Entity Framework Table Per Concrete Type Inheritance: Generate through .EDMX

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance

Can you generate a TPC inheritance structure through the entity framework designer? I have managed to get a TPC inheritance structure to work through Code First, but the database I'm connecting to has a good 20 relationship tables. I don't want to manage all of those relationships through code first.

If that is not possible, would it be possible to generate an .EDMX through code-first and then edit that through the designer?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/25/table-per-concrete-type-inheritance-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: Yes! I was trying to avoid editing the xml directly, as it is likely that other developers will need to come in and figure out quickly what is going on. Buyt if you want to put this as an answer, I'll check-mark it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gil Fink has a blog on this:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/25/table-per-concrete-type-inheritance-in-entity-framework.aspx